# Showing Sub totals in SQL Server query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT 
    BCD.[EventID],
    M.TargetCategory,
    BCD.[RoundName],
    COUNT(CASE
             WHEN R.Status_Id <> 4
                THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
          END) AS [Outstanding Events]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Event_Details] BCD
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[lkpTarget] M ON BCD.TargetID = M.TargetID
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[EventComments] R ON BCD.EventID = R.[EventID]
GROUP BY 
    BCD.[EventID], M.TargetCategory, BCD.[RoundName]
HAVING 
    COUNT(CASE
             WHEN R.Status_Id <> 4
                THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
          END) > 0
ORDER BY 
    TargetCategory ASC;
```

I have the above query showing the `[Outstanding Events]` for each `RoundName`.

Does anyone know the best way I can modify the above query such that I can show `[Outstanding Events]` sub totals grouped by `TargetCategory` and then an `[Outstanding Events]` grand total for the entire query result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`grouping sets`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (BCD.[EventID], M.TargetCategory, BCD.[RoundName]),
                         (BCD.[RoundName]),
                         ()
                       )
```